# Initialize a variable within a loop

Tags: ruby, iterator

I define a variable holding an empty object before pushing elements into it in an `each` loop (or other types of loop) like so:

```
foo = []
collection.each do |item|
  foo << item
end
foo
```

or like this:

```
foo = []
count = 0
collection.each do |item|
  count += 1
  raise ArgumentError if count > 10
  foo << item
end
foo
```

However, `foo` or `count` appears too often and clutters the code. Is there a method to shorten this chunk of code? I want to believe that the first `foo` can be placed inside the loop to run once.

Comment: Some solutions I use is using methods for this kind of simple pieces, which have the variable as local, or if used in whole object, then as `@foobar`, and then it should have proper name anyway. Sometimes I just keep it simple and regard those variables ”unused” after the loop is over, saying to myself that declaring the var always again is correct way to do it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the code? What's wrong with `foo = collection.map`? Or just... `collection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method:

```
foo = collection.inject([]) {|sum, item| sum << item }
```

`single-line block` just a Ruby style, prefer `{...}` over `do...end` for single-line blocks. Either multi-lines or just single-line blocks, you also can use the `do...end`, but for multi-lines block, `do...end` is better.

```
foo = collection.inject([]) do |sum, item| 
          sum << item
       end # This is ok, but `{...}` looks better.
```

multi lines:

```
foo = collection.inject([]) do |sum, item| 
          # line 1
          # line 2
          # and more
       end
```

> For Ruby style, you can get more info from [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution for my code sample... What if I had more lines within the loop. For example, an ArgumentError and an incremental count for each cycle. Could I use this solution to span multiple lines or is this just a one line, one action method?

Comment: Great thank you for that... I was unaware you could use a `do ... end` on something other than `for`, `each`, etc.

Comment: I believe it's more idiomatic now to use `each_with_object` rather than `inject` (or `reduce`) for the type of work he's asking about. It's faster and less prone to error because you do not have to explicitly return the accumulator.

Comment: @AaronLasseigne you are right, I tested by benchmark, the `each_with_object` is faster than `inject`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that I use in scenarios like this is [each_with_obejct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

```
collection = ['string', 1, []]
foo =
  collection.each_with_object([]) do |item,array|
    array << item
  end
#=> ['string', 1, []]
```

Likewise, if you need an index, you can chain `each_with_index` with `each_with_object` like so, but it becomes slightly more complicated:

```
collection = ['string', 1, []]

foo =
  collection.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |item_and_index,array|
    item, index = item_and_index
    raise ArgumentError if index > 10
    array << item
  end
#=> ['string', 1, []]
```

The `item_and_index` becomes an array holding the item from collection in the 0 index, and the index of the item in the 1 index each time it loops.

Comment: If you're chaining like that you can use `with_index` or `with_object` after the first one. `collection.each_with_object([]).with_index`

Comment: Nice! I was aware of the `with_index`, but reversing the order to use it would have looked funny IMO. Never used `with_object` before.